# Calculate the limit with the series of fractional powers: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+{1.5}^{\frac1n}+{1.5}^{\frac2n}+\cdots+{1.5}^{\frac{n-1}n}}n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+{1.5}^{\frac{1}{n}}+{1.5}^{\frac{2}{n}}+\cdots+{1.5}^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}{n}$$

I got $1.23315\ldots$ by computer programming, but is there any way to get the exact result?

Answer (score 7):

The numerator is just a geometric series of common ratio $1.5^{1/n}$ and you are computing

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1.5-1}{n(1.5^{1/n}-1)}=\frac{0.5}{\log 1.5}\approx1.233151731\cdots$$

by an alternative definition/property of the logarithm (or by L'Hospital).

Comment: @michaelhardy: what was the purpose of this edit, which is invisible ?

Comment: Unnecessary edit rolled back. It bothers me that all of MH's edits here have been unhelpful. Here, it was merely a choice of style for formatting of LaTeX. In the question and haqnatural's answer, more very minor LaTeX edits. I think such behavior is rather unnecessary and shouldn't be done.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : I think I was looking at it and decided nothing needed to be edited, but decided there was nothing. However, putting in a blank space often alters the way the code appears in the editing window, by preventing line-breaks from being in strange places, thereby improving legibility to the person who is editing.

Comment: Perhaps better questions are, "Why is there only one character of whitespace in your LaTeX?" and "Why didn't @MichaelHardy add a lot *more* whitespace?" It's like trying to read minified JavaScript.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It seems that Michael Hardy tried to [respond to you in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2165/2017/10/27), but since you wasn't in that chat room, his ping probably did not reach you.

Comment: @jpmc26: you needn't read my LaTex, do you ?

Answer (score 7):

$$\lim _{n\to \infty} \frac {1+1.5^{\frac 1 n}+ 1.5^{\frac 2 n}+ \cdots + 1.5^{\frac {n-1} n}} n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n 1.5^{(k-1)/n} \\
= \int_0^1 1.5^x \, dx = \frac {1.5^x}{\ln 1.5} \Bigg|_0^1 =\frac {0.5}{\ln 1.5} $$

Comment: Your MathJax code had lots of purposeless complications that were absurd and would make editing harder.

Comment: I mostly use this programe http://s1.daumcdn.net/editor/fp/service_nc/pencil/Pencil_chromestore.html,any other suggestion?

Comment: You could learn to write it yourself. In a case like this present posting it's pretty simple.

Comment: There's a typo. It should be $1.5^{(k-1)/n}$ in that summand. But other than that looks fine.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt,thank you for correction

Answer (score 6):

This is a Riemann sum for

$$\int_0^1 1.5^x \, dx = \frac{1}{2\ln 3/2} \approx 1.23315.$$

Comment: @orangezeit - do you understand WHY this is the correct answer? The connection to definite integrals? If not, just knowing the answer/solution won't help you in any way.

Comment: @mathguy Yes. Someone just posted that Riemann sum. You guys are really helpful.

Comment: Could you explain its reason please? @mathguy

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname Write down a left-hand Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 1.5^x \ dx$ with $n$ equal-sized intervals of width $\frac{1}{n}$. You should get exactly the expression inside the limit above. If you take the limit as $n\to \infty$, the value of the Riemann sums converges to the value of the integral $\int_0^1 1.5^x \ dx$.

Comment: @kccu thanks a lot